# Apache swapping virtual host entries each request

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-wsgi

I have the following httpd.conf.  Based on the different domain, it should route the request to the appropriate entry showing a different site based on a similar code base.

The problem is that it swaps between site 1 and site 2 every few requests:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite1.com
    ServerAlias mysite1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysitedjango
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysitedjango/mysite1/mysite1_wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite2.com
    ServerAlias mysite2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysitedjango
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysitedjango/mysite1/mysite2_wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>



Alias /static/ /var/www/html/mysitedjango/shared/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/mysitedjango/shared/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/mysitedjango

<Directory /var/www/html/mysitedjango>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Is there something I can do to stop this confusion from happening?

Comment: Do you have the `NameVirtualHost *:80` entry? You will need that to enable name based virtual hosting.

Comment: @Danielt. I thought what I had above is the name based virtual  hosts?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes. In order to turn on name based virtual hosts, you will need the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your Apache configuration file. Do you have that line?

Comment: @Danielt. yes I had this, but I added it here as well.